# Ошибка OpenSSL на Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong signature type

Ошибка возникает после авторризации на CAS. Если скипнуть авторизацию и просто зайти в приложение, такая ошибка не воспроизводится. 
Приложение запускается из docker, где openssl 1.1.1c. Локально - openssl 1.1.1.

```
app_1          | rack-cas: Intercepting ticket validation request.[78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298] SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong signature type
 OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong signature type):
app_1          | [78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298]   
app_1          | [78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298] /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock'
app_1          | [78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298] /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'
app_1          | [78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298] /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:996:in `connect'
app_1          | [78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298] httplog (1.3.0) lib/httplog/adapters/net_http.rb:36:in `connect'
app_1          | [78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298] /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
app_1          | [78332126-a6b4-4cdf-95a8-d15f8a9c4298] /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:919:in `start'
...
```

Comment: Куда-то идет обращение по HTTP с использованием одной из библиотек Faraday, httparty или подобной. Точнее обращение по HTTPS, а на той стороне либо сертификат протух, либо используется самоподписанный. Если это тестирование, можно добавить в соединение параметр вроде verify: false (httparty), если это продакшен - нужно чинить сертификаты со стороны источника.

Comment: в application.rb добавлен `config.rack_cas.verify_ssl_cert = false`, но все равно ошибка выходит.